# Meteor: return subset of attributes from Mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Im querying Mongo to get the user item, but I only want to pass through a subset of the info to the template. My current solution is this:

```
var returnUsers = [];
var users = Meteor.users.find().fetch();

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    returnUsers.push(users[i].profile);
}

console.log(returnUsers);
return returnUsers;
```

But I'm losing the iterator. Ideally I want to just return the profile object of each user. How do you do that?

Comment: Please try the use the second parameter of [`db.collection.find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/), such as `db.users.find({}, {_id:0, profile: 1})` to filter the profile only...

Comment: Is this code for a publication or client side?

Comment: Client side. I'm new to this by the way. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is little point in doing this on the client. Returning a cursor with fields you don't end up using from minimongo is normally just as fast or faster than filtering fields out in javascript.

*Especially* for the `Users` collection you want to filter out the extra fields in your *publication* from the server. For example:

```
Meteor.publish('allUsers',function(){
  return Meteor.users.find({},{ fields: { profile: 1 }});
});
```

This will publish the `profile` data *and* the `_id` for each user. Then when you do

```
Meteor.users.find({});
```

on the client you will only get the `profile` data and `_id` without any need to do extra filtering.

Note that the `fields` option only allows you to define a set of fields to include or exclude together. You cannot mix include and exclude:

```
{ fields: { key1: 0, key2: 1 }}
```

will fail.

There is no security benefit to filtering fields on the client either. The user has full access to the published collection from the console.

Comment: Thanks, even if I then add authentication... the users collection will be completely accessible? since I'm using an _id to route to pages where you 'view' a user, theoretically it would be possible to get any id. that combined with console access means that the db is very insecure... is there any way around this?

Comment: You need to decide which other users you want to publish (besides the logged in one) and what you want to reveal about them. It's under your control. See [Meteor security resources](http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/11/meteor-security-no-3-useful-resources.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
use `map`

var profiles=Meteor.users.find().map(function(a){return a.profile})
```

Comment: Thanks. But this will also not make use of the cursor?

Comment: Nope I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you want to keep cursor as per comment in previous answer remove the fetch as this turns it into an array not a cursor and add fields like below

`return Meteor.users.find({},{fields:{profile:1}});`

This won't give you *only* profile but will also return the id as this is always sent regardless of the fields specified to return.

Comment: If you want to remove the _id as well, I think you can do _id: 0 in the fields object.

Comment: How does minimongo behave when you do that though?